# DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET During Join Ubuntu to Domain

Tags: 12.04, server

When I'm trying to join Ubuntu client machine to domain server I'm getting this error:

```
Error: DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET [code 0x0000251e]
A bad packet was received from a DNS server. Potentially the requested address
does not exist.
```

Comment: We are talking about Windows AD? How do you join? Is the firewall off on both systems? Is the DNS name known on both systems? Your DNS has a reverse lookup zone? What does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` show?

Comment: Yes i am talking about windows AD. I'm joining through windows active directory as well as through command also sudo domainjoin-cli join fqdn.of.your.domain Administrator. Dns name also known. when i execute cat /etc/resolv.conf  showing this " # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
"

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs when `/etc/resolv.conf` is not setup properly.

Here is a sample resolv.conf:

```
domain     domain.tld
search     domain.tld
nameserver <ip address of domain DNS server>
nameserver <ip address of domain DNS server>
```

Comment: Depending on your version of Ubuntu, this answer may be misleading/incorrect.  As OP detailed in his question, he is seeing a nameserver value of 127.0.0.1 which is not incorrect assuming he is using DNSMASQ as detailed in this article: http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and spent 5 days trawling through forums. In the end I found a little note about DNS being picky about the spelling.

I fixed this by ensuring I used the uppercase letters in the FQDN where necessary. Windows doesn't care about upper and lower case but Linux does so try that.

The command I used was sudo domainjoin-cli join --disable ssh {domain name} {domain admin account name}

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by a second DNS server not being the domain controller.

I had 1 main DNS+DHCP server and 1 DNS+Active Directory server. The DNS records pointed the domain to the Active Directory server. But the DHCP was declaring itself as the DNS to use.

I solved the problem declaring in the DHCP that the DNS server was the DNS+Active Directory server. Apparently the joining is disrupted when the DNS server in use by the client is not the same Active Directory server.